# Couchbase Client for php not work

Tags: php, couchbase

I download the source code from https://github.com/couchbase/php-ext-couchbase. I then I compile it in ubuntu use the following command .

```
  $ phpize
  $ ./configure
  $ make
  $ make test.
```

Then I got a couchbase.so in module , then I include the couchbase.so in php.ini. Then, restart the Apache. However, where I check the server with phpinfo(), I cannot find any couchbase module is installed.

Then when I run

```
         $myCluster = new CouchbaseCluster('couchbase://couchbase:8091');

         $cb = new Couchbase("couchbase:8091", "testbucket",
                "testpassword", "test_bosh_bucket");
```

In apache log , I found that the error message is CouchbaseCluster Class is not found. And Couchbase class is not found. It seems PHP does not load the couchbase.so. Since I cannot find the couchbase in phpinfo() and the Class is not found. Anything that I am missed?
Please help. Thank,s

Comment: Is the edited php.ini being loaded? or loading another php.ini. Can be found in `phpinfo()` page.

Comment: Do you need to `make install` at the end?
I would just use `pecl install couchbase` personally unless there is a fix you need from the master branch.

Answer (score 0):

Install http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/c-2.4/download-install.html
I'm use:

```
<?php
$cluster = new CouchbaseCluster("192.168.0.90:8091", "Administrator", "password", "default");
$db = $cluster->openBucket('default');
for ($i = 1; $i <= 400; $i++) {

$DocumentName = "document_name_" . substr(md5(rand()), 0, 6);
$res = $db->insert($DocumentName, array("user_id" => md5(rand())));

var_dump($res);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use DLLs that match your PHP version. Please refer to below link. Use the Thread Safe version.

http://pecl.php.net/package/couchbase/1.1.5/windows

Then, use the following code.

```
$cb = new Couchbase("127.0.0.1:8091", "", "", "beer-sample");
$cb->set("foo", "bar");
var_dump("foo");
```

Note: Don't use accounts with admin permissions to perform data transactions. Either pass NULL as the username or name of the bucket.